# Authenticate to Google Drive services account without json file in .net

Tags: json, vb.net, google-drive-api

I want to authenticate my vb.net Winform application to access my Google drive account. It works fine if I use a json file. But I want to avoid having a plain json file lying around the file system with my private keys in it. Especially when I am going to install the application on another machine.

So I tried to hardcode the credential parameters, with no luck so far. This is what I have tried:

```
Public Function Authenticate() As DriveService
    
    Dim scope As String = DriveService.Scope.Drive
    Dim credential As GoogleCredential 
    Dim params As New JsonCredentialParameters
    
    With params
    .Type = JsonCredentialParameters.ServiceAccountCredentialType
    .ProjectId = "myprojid"
    .PrivateKeyId = "mykeyid"
    .PrivateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n myprivatekey =\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    .ClientEmail = "myappname@myprojid.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    .ClientId = "12345"
    End With
    
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromJsonParameters(params).CreateScoped(scope)
    
    Return New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential, .ApplicationName = "GoogleDriveDownloader"})
    
End Function
```

and also this similar approach:

```
Public Function CreateServiceCredentials() As GoogleCredential

    Dim parameters = New JsonCredentialParameters With {
    .Type = JsonCredentialParameters.ServiceAccountCredentialType,
    .ProjectId = "myprojid",
    .PrivateKeyId = "mykeyid",
    .PrivateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n myprivatekey =\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    .ClientEmail = "myappname@myprojid.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    .ClientId = "12345"
        }

    Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters)
    Dim stream = New MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json))
    Return GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)

End Function
```

In both cases I get the error: ArgumentException: PKCS8 data must be contained within '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' and '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'. Arg_ParamName_Name

If I remove the trailing \n I get the error: FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While not an answer, I'm a little lost how you can read the credentials from a json file and have it work, yet using the same credentials via code doesn't.  How exactly where you getting these creds from the file and setting them?

Comment: @Hursey , I just opened the json file I downloaded from the Google management console via text editor. The private key is plainly written in this form:
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n privateKey =\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",

Might a wrongful copying be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself, or let's call it a workaround for it:

I just took the whole text of the json file, put it into a winforms textbox and called:

```
credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(txt_Credentials.Text).CreateScoped(scope)
```

Meh, it works ;-)